# HTML Going Off the Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a contact app to build my portfolio.

```js
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image_input");
var uploaded_image = "";

image_input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        uploaded_image = reader.result;
        document.querySelector("#display_image").style.backgroundImage = `url(${uploaded_image})`
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
})

document.body.onload=function(){var e=".draggable{cursor: move;display: inline-block;} .text{display: inline-block; cursor: move;} .text:focus{cursor: auto;} .text-wrapper{width: 100%;position: relative;} .wrap{position: absolute;margin: y;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;}';",t=document.createElement("style");t.styleSheet?t.styleSheet.cssText=e:t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e)),document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t);var n,o,i=document.querySelectorAll(".draggable"),a=document.querySelectorAll(".text");z=1,editing=!1;var r=null;function s(e){event.target.classList.contains("text")||(editing=!1,editing&&n.blur())}document.body.addEventListener("mousedown",s),document.body.addEventListener("touchstart",s);for(var d=0;d<i.length;d++)i[d].addEventListener("mousedown",c),i[d].addEventListener("touchstart",f),b=i[d].getBoundingClientRect(),i[d].initialOffsetX=b.left+window.pageXOffset,i[d].initialOffsetY=b.top+window.pageYOffset,i[d].x=b.left,i[d].y=b.top,i[d].style.cursor="move",document.addEventListener("mouseup",g),document.addEventListener("touchend",g);for(let e=0;e<a.length;e++){var l;a[e].addEventListener("dblclick",u),(l=document.createElement("div")).className="text-wrapper",a[e].parentNode.insertBefore(l,a[e]),l.appendChild(a[e]),l.style.height=p(a[e])+"px",(l=document.createElement("div")).className="wrap",a[e].parentNode.insertBefore(l,a[e]),l.appendChild(a[e]),a[e].contentEditable="true"}function u(e){n=e.target,editing=!0,n.focus()}function f(e){e.preventDefault(),c(e),null==r?r=setTimeout(function(){r=null},500):(clearTimeout(r),r=null,u(e))}function c(e){if(e.target.classList.contains("text")||(editing=!1,editing&&n.blur()),!editing){e.preventDefault(),moving=!0,z+=1,(o=e.target).attributeName="test",b=o.getBoundingClientRect();var t=b.left+window.pageXOffset,i=b.top+window.pageYOffset;offsetX=e.pageX||e.changedTouches[0].pageX,offsetY=e.pageY||e.changedTouches[0].pageY,document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){if(!0===moving){var n="transform: translate("+(e.pageX-offsetX+t-o.initialOffsetX)+"px, "+(e.pageY-offsetY+i-o.initialOffsetY)+"px);z-index:"+z+";";o.setAttribute("style",n)}}),document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(e){var n=e.changedTouches;if(!0===moving)for(let e=0;e<n.length;e++){var a="transform: translate("+(n[e].pageX-offsetX+t-o.initialOffsetX)+"px, "+(n[e].pageY-offsetY+i-o.initialOffsetY)+"px);z-index:"+z+";";o.setAttribute("style",a)}})}}function g(e){moving=!1}function p(e){var t=e.offsetHeight,n=getComputedStyle(e);return t+=parseInt(n.marginTop)+parseInt(n.marginBottom)}};



var i = 0;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicater' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
   clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    // event handlers are not cloned
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 

    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    
}


#display_image{
    width: 75px;
    height:75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=“/resources/demos/style.css”>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <style>
  #sortable {  margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 200%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0px 300px 405px ; padding: 1em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 20px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 
<ul id="sortable" style=" border:3px; border-style:solid; background-color: #E9E395; border-color:transparent; padding: 1em; width:fit-content; width:-webkit-fit-content; width:-moz-fit-content;">
  
  
  
  <div id="duplicater0"> 
    
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><input type= "file" id="image_input" accepts="image/png, image/jpg"> 
    
    <div id="display_image"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <form>
       <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align: left" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
         First Name
       </textarea>
     <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "last name">
         Last Name
       </textarea>
    </form>
    <form>
      <textarea  style="border:3px; text-align: left; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
        Phone #
      </textarea>
    <a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif"><b>Text </b></a><a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif">|</a><a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif"><b> Call</b></a>
    </form>


    <form>
      <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align: left" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
        Occupation
      </textarea>
  
   </form>


    




          
           <button onclick="duplicate()">Add</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
   
  </li> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
 
</div>


  
</ul>
 
 
</body>



</html>
```

When I press the "add" button below occupation, the HTML at the top gets cut off. I've tried editing the padding but to no avail. The bottom has no cut-off when I press add. I also used "break" for some space. I suspect it's something with the padding but no too sure.

```js
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image_input");
var uploaded_image = "";

image_input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        uploaded_image = reader.result;
        document.querySelector("#display_image").style.backgroundImage = `url(${uploaded_image})`
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
})

document.body.onload=function(){var e=".draggable{cursor: move;display: inline-block;} .text{display: inline-block; cursor: move;} .text:focus{cursor: auto;} .text-wrapper{width: 100%;position: relative;} .wrap{position: absolute;margin: y;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;}';",t=document.createElement("style");t.styleSheet?t.styleSheet.cssText=e:t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e)),document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t);var n,o,i=document.querySelectorAll(".draggable"),a=document.querySelectorAll(".text");z=1,editing=!1;var r=null;function s(e){event.target.classList.contains("text")||(editing=!1,editing&&n.blur())}document.body.addEventListener("mousedown",s),document.body.addEventListener("touchstart",s);for(var d=0;d<i.length;d++)i[d].addEventListener("mousedown",c),i[d].addEventListener("touchstart",f),b=i[d].getBoundingClientRect(),i[d].initialOffsetX=b.left+window.pageXOffset,i[d].initialOffsetY=b.top+window.pageYOffset,i[d].x=b.left,i[d].y=b.top,i[d].style.cursor="move",document.addEventListener("mouseup",g),document.addEventListener("touchend",g);for(let e=0;e<a.length;e++){var l;a[e].addEventListener("dblclick",u),(l=document.createElement("div")).className="text-wrapper",a[e].parentNode.insertBefore(l,a[e]),l.appendChild(a[e]),l.style.height=p(a[e])+"px",(l=document.createElement("div")).className="wrap",a[e].parentNode.insertBefore(l,a[e]),l.appendChild(a[e]),a[e].contentEditable="true"}function u(e){n=e.target,editing=!0,n.focus()}function f(e){e.preventDefault(),c(e),null==r?r=setTimeout(function(){r=null},500):(clearTimeout(r),r=null,u(e))}function c(e){if(e.target.classList.contains("text")||(editing=!1,editing&&n.blur()),!editing){e.preventDefault(),moving=!0,z+=1,(o=e.target).attributeName="test",b=o.getBoundingClientRect();var t=b.left+window.pageXOffset,i=b.top+window.pageYOffset;offsetX=e.pageX||e.changedTouches[0].pageX,offsetY=e.pageY||e.changedTouches[0].pageY,document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){if(!0===moving){var n="transform: translate("+(e.pageX-offsetX+t-o.initialOffsetX)+"px, "+(e.pageY-offsetY+i-o.initialOffsetY)+"px);z-index:"+z+";";o.setAttribute("style",n)}}),document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(e){var n=e.changedTouches;if(!0===moving)for(let e=0;e<n.length;e++){var a="transform: translate("+(n[e].pageX-offsetX+t-o.initialOffsetX)+"px, "+(n[e].pageY-offsetY+i-o.initialOffsetY)+"px);z-index:"+z+";";o.setAttribute("style",a)}})}}function g(e){moving=!1}function p(e){var t=e.offsetHeight,n=getComputedStyle(e);return t+=parseInt(n.marginTop)+parseInt(n.marginBottom)}};



var i = 0;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicater' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
   clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    // event handlers are not cloned
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 

    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    
}


#display_image{
    width: 75px;
    height:75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=“/resources/demos/style.css”>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <style>
  #sortable {  margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 200%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0px 300px 405px ; padding: 1em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 20px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 
<ol id="sortable" style=" border:3px; border-style:solid; background-color: #E9E395; border-color:transparent; padding: 1em; width:fit-content; width:-webkit-fit-content; width:-moz-fit-content;">
  
  
  
  <div id="duplicater0"> 
    
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><input type= "file" id="image_input" accepts="image/png, image/jpg"> 
    
    <div id="display_image"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <form>
       <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align: left" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
         First Name
       </textarea>
     <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "last name">
         Last Name
       </textarea>
    </form>
    <form>
      <textarea  style="border:3px; text-align: left; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
        Phone #
      </textarea>
    <a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif"><b>Text </b></a><a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif">|</a><a style="color: #B8B8B8; font-size: medium; font-family:serif"><b> Call</b></a>
    </form>


    <form>
      <textarea  style="border:3px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align: left" rows = "1" cols = "15" name = "first name">
        Occupation
      </textarea>
  
   </form>


    




          
           <button onclick="duplicate()">Add</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
   
  </li> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
 
</div>


  
</ol>
 
 
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because when you click the add button you have margin values on all of your list items `#sortable li` of `margin: 0px 300px 405px;` which includes adding a bottom margin value of 405px on your related `<li>` elements. So when you add an item it creates that extra margin, pushing it out of view.

Also, your `<ol>` element with id `#sortable` has a `width: 200%`, you need to make that `width: 100%` as follows and add `box-sizing: border-box` so any padding values remain inside the element as opposed to adding extra-width horizontally as well.

```
#sortable {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

My suggestion for the other problem would be to use the `flex` display property for your page layout. There is a very good set of flexbox tutorials here:

[Flexbox tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj7NZ6FiQvo)

Answer (score 1):

I added flex to the unordered list and set the color of the html tag to the same color as the unordered list tag.

```css
html{
    background-color: #E9E395
}



ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
```